# Can't compile GL ES 2.0 Shader

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've done a simple API on top of GLES2. Everything seems OK, but the state of `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` is `GL_FALSE`.

I've got a structure like this:

```
typedef struct MyGLShader__
{
    GLuint uiHandle;
    GLenum eType;   
    const char *pcSource;

} MyGLShader;
```

I initialize it this way and create a shader using a function of mine:

```
MyGLShader shader = {0, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, MY_VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE};
shader_create(&shader);
```

This function should be creating the shader:

```
MyStatus shader_create(MyGLShader *pShader)
{
    MyStatus eStatus;

    pShader->uiHandle = glCreateShader(pShader->eType);
    MY_GL_VALIDATE("glCreateShader");

    glShaderSource(pShader->uiHandle, 1, &pShader->pcSource, NULL);
    MY_GL_VALIDATE("glShaderSource");

    glCompileShader(pShader->uiHandle);
    eStatus = shader_check(pShader);
    if (eStatus != MY_STATUS_OK)
    {
        return eStatus;
    }

    return MY_STATUS_OK;
}
```

It goes without trouble until it calls `shader_check()`:

```
static MyStatus shader_check(MyGLShader *pShader)
{
    GLint status;
    LOGI("Checking shader compilation status...");

    glGetShaderiv(pShader->uiHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if (status != GL_TRUE)
    {
        LOGE("Shader compilation has failed");
        shader_log_infolog(pShader);

        return MY_STATUS_ERROR;
    }

    return MY_STATUS_OK;
}
```

Which stumbles on: `if (status != GL_TRUE)`.

After that, when it tries to print the infolog in `shader_log_infolog`:

```
static void shader_log_infolog(
        MyGLShader *pShader, MyStatus eStatus)
{
    char acbuffer[INFO_LENGTH];

    glGetShaderInfoLog(pShader->uiHandle, INFO_LENGTH, NULL, (char *) &acbuffer);
    LOGE("Shader Log: %s", acbuffer)
}
```

It doesn't print any log, i.e. it only prints

> Shader Log:

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong with the initialization. `MY_GL_VALIDATE` checks for gl errors using `glGetError()` and I can confirm it works fine.

### UPDATE

Here's the Shader source definition:

```
#define MY_VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE \
                                \
"                               \
attribute   vec4 a_Position;    \
                                \
void main() {                   \
    gl_Position = a_Position;   \
}                               \
                                \
"
```

Comment: Err?... maybe?... you could?... show us the shader that doesn't compile?

Comment: Actually, there seems to be some other problem. I seem not to have intialized the EGL properly and it's working in GLES1 mode instead of GLES2. :-) At least I think that may be the problem. As the shader is dead simple. And something other that's funny is that all handle creating functions like glCreateProgram(), glGetAttribLocation(), etc, seem to be returning *always* `43`. Pretty fishy.

Comment: Too bad they don't return `42` ;) Sounds really strange.

Comment: OK. I had forgotten to setup the EGL to use GLES2. It was using the defaults which are for GLES1. Strangely enough, the drivers didn't complain for using GLES2 functions in a GLES1 context. Hah.

Comment: Can you put that as the answer so it doesn't appear on the unanswered list.

Comment: OK. I'll write one this weekend.

Comment: It would be appropriate to close this question by putting the answer in the system. In the way it is right now, this open question just makes confusion for the end users and for people willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to setup the EGL to use GLES2. It was using the defaults which are for GLES1. Strangely enough, the drivers didn't complain for using GLES2 functions in a GLES1 context.